# How to change content on the same side, as user logged in

Tags: html, jsp, session, servlets

I'm using html, servlets and session atm. Trying to delve into jsp and how it works.

I'm working on a site, and as a user succesful login using a servlet, I then want to let the user stay on the same page, but the content should be changed. e.g. The login div should be gone, and instead there could be a "Welcome x".

Would it be possible to do the above using jsp, session and servlets? And if a small example could be given I'd be grateful.

Comment: So, you want to use AJAX? Yes, it's possible. And the server-side part wouldn't change much from what you already have. What would change the most os the client-side part: forms and links would be submitted using JavaScript. Google for AJAX.

Comment: I think, its entirely possible. First tell me how do you confirm a user's presence? Using session or something else?

Comment: The user first login with email and password, and clicks submit. Then a servlet checks with a mysql, and then start a session.